# xcode build failing when creating main.jsbundle

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, mobile, xcodebuild

I am running xcodebuild archive to create app file of my iOS React Native project.

```
+ node /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ios-react-native-build-shell/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ios-react-native-build-shell/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/myApp.app/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ios-react-native-build-shell/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/myApp.app
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.

Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'transformFile' of undefined
    at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ios-react-native-build-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:78:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ios-react-native-build-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:18:30)
    at /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ios-react-native-build-shell/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:29:15
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I am facing this issue, when react-native is trying to create the main.jsbundle file. What could be the issue?

Comment: is this project using Expo?

Comment: No, I am not using Expo.